# Visibility of expanding last view in the expandable RecyclerView

Tags: android-recyclerview, expandable

[image]

I want the  things in the last expandable item to be fully visible when it is clicked,Now what is happening means when I click on last item it expands down, but I manually need to scroll up again to see the the things inside the expanded item.How can the last expandable item be fully visible.
I am using Recyclerview.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found the solution which I wanted, I used

> recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(selectedPosition);

after setting the adapter. So now the things in the last expandable item is fully visible when it is clicked.

Comment: How to determine selectedPosition? Is it a ParentItemIndex which has been clicked? please provide example

Answer (score 0):

Just a supplementary:
If you use h6ah4i/advrecyclerview, you can use the following code snippet:

```
    @Override
    public boolean onHookGroupExpand(int groupPosition, boolean fromUser) {
        // NOTE21: collapse all other groups when one item expand.
        mExpMgr.collapseAll();

        // NOTE21: Visibility of expanding last view in the expandable recyclerview
        if (groupPosition == getGroupCount() - 1) {
            mRecyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(groupPosition + getChildCount(groupPosition));
        }
        return true;
    }
```