# Expanding Last Item of CardView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

Please don't mark it as a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39911518/visiblity-of-expanding-last-view-in-the-expandable-recyclerview).

I am trying Collapsable `CardView` but the last card when expanded doesn't push its content upwards, rather the user has to explicitly scroll down. I have tried the mentioned ways but all in vain. This is happening.

[image]

This might be achieved using some library but I don't prefer it. I think I need to get the position of the current card and then apply logic.

Here's my implementation of the Adapter:

```
public class RVAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyViewHolder> {

private ArrayList<AppItem> appItemList;
private Context context;

RVAdapter(ArrayList<AppItem> appItemList, Context context) {
    this.appItemList = appItemList;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View layoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.card_list_item, parent, false);
    return new MyViewHolder(layoutView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final AppItem item = appItemList.get(position);
    holder.description.setText(item.getDescription());
    holder.title.setText(item.getTitle());
    holder.appImage.setBackgroundResource(item.getImageID());

    holder.button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return this.appItemList.size();
}
}
```

The ViewHolder:-

```
class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

ImageView appImage;
TextView title;
TextView description;
Button button;

MyViewHolder(final View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    this.appImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);
    this.title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
    this.description = itemView.findViewById(R.id.description);
    this.button = itemView.findViewById(R.id.button);

    itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            LinearLayout expandableView = view.findViewById(R.id.expandable_view);
            expandableView.setVisibility(expandableView.getVisibility() == View.GONE ?
            View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
        }
    });
}

}
```

Comment: I think it is possible by using an external wrapper https://github.com/janishar/PlaceHolderView

Comment: Can we do this without using the library?

Comment: Do you perform `smoothScrollToPosition()`?

Comment: How to perform it @azizbekian? I came to know about this, but where to implement?

Comment: Share some code in order to get some help.

Comment: I have updated my code @azizbekian

Comment: @Rohn Did my solution solved your problem ?

Answer (score 1):

Use can use this method inside on create of your Activity/fragment:

```
private void bindView() {
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    mRecyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    mRecyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerTouchListener(getActivity(), mRecyclerView, new RecyclerTouchListener.ClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(final View view, final int position)
        {
            if (mRecyclerView != null)
            {


                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void run()
                    {
                        scrollToView(scrollView,view);
                    }
                },500);
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onLongClick(View view, int position)
        {

        }
    }));
}
```

Related methods called:

```
/** scrolling items as per child inside child**/
private void scrollToView(final ScrollView scrollViewParent, final View view) {
    // Get deepChild Offset
    Point childOffset = new Point();
    getDeepChildOffset(scrollViewParent, view.getParent(), view, childOffset);
    // Scroll to child.
    scrollViewParent.smoothScrollTo(0, childOffset.y);
}
private void getDeepChildOffset(final ViewGroup mainParent, final ViewParent parent, final View child, final Point accumulatedOffset) {
    ViewGroup parentGroup = (ViewGroup) parent;
    accumulatedOffset.x += child.getLeft();
    accumulatedOffset.y += child.getTop();
    if (parentGroup.equals(mainParent)) {
        return;
    }
    getDeepChildOffset(mainParent, parentGroup.getParent(), parentGroup, accumulatedOffset);
}
```

class `RecyclerTouchListener`:

```
public class RecyclerTouchListener implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener {

private GestureDetector gestureDetector;
private ClickListener clickListener;

public RecyclerTouchListener(Context context, final RecyclerView recyclerView, final ClickListener clickListener) {
    this.clickListener = clickListener;
    gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
            View child = recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
            if (child != null && clickListener != null) {
                clickListener.onLongClick(child, recyclerView.getChildPosition(child));
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {

    View child = rv.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
    if (child != null && clickListener != null && gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)) {
        clickListener.onClick(child, rv.getChildPosition(child));
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
}

@Override
public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {

}

public interface ClickListener {
    void onClick(View view, int position);

    void onLongClick(View view, int position);
}}
```

Try this out and let me know in comments

Comment: In `scrollToView` method inside handler how to use ScrollView? I am not using ScrollView!

Comment: @Rohn Just make the parent layout as Scrollview in your activity/fragment then you are good to go, let me know if you need any help. This is a working solution and I ma using it in my app.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [`requestChildRectangleOnScreen`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.LayoutManager.html#requestChildRectangleOnScreen(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView,%20android.view.View,%20android.graphics.Rect,%20boolean,%20boolean)) of `RecyclerView.LayoutManager` to see if it does what you need.

> *requestChildRectangleOnScreen*
>
> Requests that the given child of the RecyclerView be positioned onto the screen.

Here is some sample code that will move the last visible child of a `RecyclerView` on screen once the `RecyclerView` is idle. This is not exactly what you are looking for, but you can adapt it to your needs.

```
recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
        super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
        if (newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
            LinearLayoutManager llm = (LinearLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager();
            int lastPos = llm.findLastVisibleItemPosition();
            View lastView = llm.findViewByPosition(lastPos);
            Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, lastView.getWidth(), lastView.getHeight());
            llm.requestChildRectangleOnScreen(recyclerView, lastView, rect, false);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'll try to modify it.